# Receiving Cannot GET/ Error NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning how to use NodeJS and Express, and I'm having trouble loading pages using express. I'm able to load static pages (index.html works fine), but having trouble with anything dynamic; in this case, I keep receiving the error "Cannot GET /store.html". Would someone be able to explain what is happening?

**server.js**

```js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/store', function(req, res) {
    res.render('store.ejs', {
        FOO: foo
    })
})
```

**file structure**

```
server.js
public
    index.html
views
    store.ejs
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be using /store to access the store.ejs template not /store.html

Comment: Answers like this should be a comment under the question. Good answers comes with a working example.

Comment: When I change the path to store.ejs, it gives me a download link.